Add more than two objects using driver distance
I'm currently working on a project and using the driver distance feature. I'm curious if it's possible to add more than two objects. Has anyone tried this before? Any advice or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the file: 

what do you mean with target? a distance is a value between two objects. Not between three (what distance should Blender take? a-b a-c b-c !?) or do you mean two distances between (let's say 4 objects) - that should be possible

You can calculate two distances by adding a new variable but as Chris stated you can't calculate the distance between 3 points ? or do you want a cumulative length ?

Thanks for the comments!  I was actually following this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5SdKAUsjcsg and wondered if it would be possible to have it effect more then one object

Assuming you wanna change your object's color to the color of the nearest object: yes, it would be possible, but makes less sense, because you would have to add a distance for each object to each other object. e.g. if you have 4 objects, each object must have 3 distances. So a total of 12 distances. So you would click "a lot". I think the task could be done much easier with GN or AN (geometry nodes / animation nodes)

Thanks for answering! Could you point me in the direction of geometry nodes / animation nodes?
